# Stripped end of line white-space formatting in Parse.com string field

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I have text stored on [Parse.com](https://parse.com) in the filed of type string. 
The text consists of white-spaces such as end of line character/ new line

While displaying this text in HTML like `paragraph.get('text')` the new line characters are stripped.

How can I display the entire text with its formatting in HTML?

Comment: Is parse stripping the whitespace?  If it isn't, then this question isn't about parse.com at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:  Put your text between two pre tags:

```
<pre>
 Text in a pre element
 is displayed in a fixed-width
 font, and it preserves
 both      spaces and
 line breaks
</pre>
```

Options 2: use a regular expression (tons of examples out there) to replace your newline characters with something like a < br /> tag